как переделать py в apk
мне нужно что-бы человек на устройстве android запустил мой код как приложение apk .Написан код на phyton с использованием turtle код максимально простой фактически просто запуускаешь а он тебе рисует . Как мне это сделать фактически просто py в apk в идеале отправьте видео но можно и написать.

Смотрите kivy или beeware. Но turtle использовать не получится.

Конвертация .py в .apk скорее всего не самая лучшая идея в вашем случае
Достаточно скачать на телефон интерпретатор Python (например: PyDroid3) и запустить код в нём
Конвертировать в .apk есть смысл более масштабные проекты
